# Custom "New Item or Edit This list" button

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a requirement to create a custom "New item or edit this list" button for a quick edit view of a SP list. Here are the details:

- I need to prevent users from creating new items. I only need the "edit this list" and "Stop editing this list" functions.
- I can easily hide the "new item" button via CSS, however the "or" text still remains.
- Ideally, I'm looking for the exact same functionality (meaning the "stop editing this list" function would only appear after the grid is open and active).

Any ideas for a custom HTML button that would achieve this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Put the 'new item' button AND the 'or' inside a span, and hide the span rather than just the button

Comment: Can you elaborate? Those controls are provided OOTB by SharePoint. Are you suggesting I edit the html via SPD or some other means? If so, how can I find this snippet of HTML within SPD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference this is the code I used to generate the HTML buttons and the JS function. It works beautifully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<button id="quickedit" onclick="QuickEditFunction();return false;"><h4 id="attestheader">Edit Data</h4></button>

<script>
function QuickEditFunction()
{
InitGridFromView(window['WPQ4SchemaData'].View);
}
</script>
</td>


<td>
<body>
<button id="quickedit" onclick="ExitGridFunction(); return false;"><h4 id="attestheader">Save Changes</h4></button>

<script>
function ExitGridFunction() 
{
ExitGrid(window['WPQ4SchemaData'].View);
}  
</script>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `WPQ4SchemaData` reference must be changed to reflect your list webpart numerical ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into the script editor web part in list view page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            if($("a[title^='Edit this list using Quick Edit mode']").length>0){
                var editBtnHtml=$("a[title^='Edit this list using Quick Edit mode']")[0].outerHTML+" this list";
                $(".ms-list-addnew").html(editBtnHtml); 
            }                   
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]